# How to format or get date in local time or time zone in couchdb view map reduce?

Tags: time, view, mapreduce, timezone, couchdb

I have a database in couchDB, a field type datetime, but when i show in view (map) the data show in format ISO. I want to show in localtime, how to format? i tried with two function but not work with javascript function toString() or toLocalString() not work

Answer (score 1):

I publish the answer that worked for me after searching and searching, I leave you a complete example of the view in map reduce and how I convert the date from standard format to local format. In this case I use -6 which is the Central American time zone.

```
function(doc){
    if(doc.entrada!==null){
        var d = new Date(doc.entrada);
        d.setTime(d.getTime() - 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);      
        var[mes,dia,anho]= d.toLocaleString().split(',')[0].split('/');      
        emit([anho,mes.padStart(2,'0'),dia.padStart(2,'0'),doc.idEmpleado], d.toLocaleString());
}
```

I declare var datetime from field datetime

```
var d=new Date(doc.entrada);
```

change time-zone to UTC-6

```
d.setTime(d.getTime() - 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

if change time-zone to UTC-4

```
d.setTime(d.getTime() - 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

So I managed to change the format of the date for the view in couchdb, you can use the javascript functions toLocalString() toString() to convert to a string, it will be displayed in the zone / time that you have configured on the server, then it is a thing to do split and you're done.
I hope it works for you and helps you.

Comment: I suggest storing date & time as UTC so there is less cognitive load for consumers of the data.